# The Invincible sequence

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

Hint every 24 hours for 3 days.

Find the next number in the sequence mentioned below

7, 14, 2, 7, 10, 1, 46, 24, 40, 45, 6, 15 ...

Hint 1

> Read the title

Hint 2

> Invincible (2006)

Hint 3

> Philadelphia Eagles

Hint 4

> Superbowl Winners

Comment: 30 minutes is not 24 hours... :o)

Comment: @DanielMathias, XD

apparently I found another hint to give away, so today, tomorrow & day after for the hints and finally the answer

Comment: The question ask to find the next number, right?

Comment: @Toby, yes your understanding is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it got a little too simple with the last hint. But here goes...

> In 1948, they won against Cardinals with 7-0. The following year, 14-0. This matches the first two numbers.

So...

> assuming every number represents a year, then from [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Philadelphia_Eagles_seasons), the following number is 1960. The won against Packers with 17-13. This makes the next number 17.

However...

> The numbers in between does not signify wins, since they did not win. I suppose the numbers correspond to the number of points they got at their last win or loss in the season each year.

Comment: yup thats correct

Comment: So, the numbers are the points in their last game of each year?

Comment: I had some trouble finding statistics from the games.

Comment: its from the super bowl finals. From first Philadelphia Eagles victory to their last one(before 1960 victory)(the one this mentioned movie was about)